# How to test PL/SQL procs involving arrays from Toad?

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a need to test a stored procedure involving arrays that are written in PL/SQL.  I have no way of seeing the PL/SQL contents (shop rules) but need to call the proc.  I'd like to know how to call the following proc that invovles 3 arrays of integers directly from toad.  The method signature looks like this.

Procedure persistChanges(myKey in NUMBER, arrayOfIntsFirst numberTableType, arrayOfIntsSecond numberTableType, arrayOfIntsThird numberTableType).

How can I call a PL/SQL proc in TOAD where I can hard-code the values for the paramters to test the proc?  I'm told there's no way this could be done in Toad.  Much appreciated!!!

I have to believe there's a way to poplate these variables but just not sure how to go about doing so...

```
DECLARE 
  myKey NUMBER;
  arrayOfIntsFirst PL/SQL TABLE;
  arrayOfIntsSecond PL/SQL TABLE;
  arrayOfIntsThird PL/SQL TABLE;

BEGIN 
  myKey := NULL;
  -- arrayOfIntsFirst := NULL;  Modify the code to initialize this parameter
  -- arrayOfIntsSecond := NULL;  Modify the code to initialize this parameter
  -- arrayOfIntsThird := NULL;  Modify the code to initialize this parameter

  MY_SCHEMA.PKG_MYPACKAGE.PERSISTCHANGES ( myKey, arrayOfIntsFirst, 
  arrayOfIntsSecond,  arrayOfIntsThird );
COMMIT; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
declare
  l_nums t_num_tab;
begin
  l_nums := t_num_tab();
  l_nums.extend(2);
  l_nums(1) := 56;
  l_nums(2) := 42;

  for i in l_nums.first .. l_nums.last
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line( 'Number is: ' || l_nums(i) );
  end loop;
end;
```

And Toad is just a development environment, it won't limit you from writing an anonymous block like above.  The t_num_tab is defined as a table of numbers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_num_tab as table of number;
```

You don't even need to formally extend the collection first and assign values.  You can initialize in one step:

```
declare
  l_nums t_num_tab;
begin
  l_nums := t_num_tab(23,89,152);

...
end;
```

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00504).  Hope that helps.